# Make permanent layer in ArcMap, Image Analysis Functions to display hillshade

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, hillshade

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

I want to make relief map, so that it looks good at all scales. I used the hillshade function but after exporting the data, the relief looks good only at one scale.

I'm using this method:
[Using Image Analysis Functions to Display Layer Tints on Hillshades](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0612/using-image-analysis-functions-to-display-layer-tints-on-hillshades.html)

How can I save the result without loss of quality?

P.S. I already tried to use mosaic.

Comment: I've been using the same techniques described in the linked article without any issues. I experience no loss of quality when i export. Can you add more info and provide visual examples?  All i can think of is that your input data is low resolution and it appears (correctly) as if you were seeing loss in quality at large scales.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97304/hillshade-is-block-grey-arcgis/97538#97538) a post where I discuss hilshade. In the answer I am suggesting the geoprocessing tool [HillShade for Spatial Analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000v0000000).

The method that I use to overlay the hillshade on the classified raster is fairly basic and you may want to experiment with the overlay settings but it should be visually pleasing at most scales - Nothing is ever going to look *good* zoomed in until you see the pixels.