# Disappearing layers in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, layers, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have DEM hillshade layers which I have tried to change the base heights to floating surfaces.

I have done this with these layers before but had to change them back and forth to do some analysis.

They keep disappearing and not coming back.

Can anyone tell me how to stop this from happening?

Comment: I also have this problem, and at this point I'm convinced its a bug in either video drivers or ArcScene itself. I'd try updating your drivers, but I have no idea if it will solve the problem.

Comment: @Wes Could both of you confirm whether your computers are using AMD graphics cards? I ask in relation to comments I made on an answer in one of Katie's [earlier questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97304/hillshade-is-block-grey-arcgis).

Comment: @ChrisW Not AMD. I have a NVIDIA Quadro 600

Comment: Hi, I'm not actually sure. I'm on a university computer. Do you know how to check?

Comment: I had the same issue if I use FGDB raster (extracted by a mask previously) and when I convert this to TIFF, the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the "Factor to convert layer elevation values to scene units", in the "Base Heights" tab, is not changing to another number.

If you are using geographical coordinates and meters, try using 0.000015 as value.

Answer (score 0):

It's the projection. You're in ArcScene so be sure all of your layers are in Conic!